# Помогите с регулярным выражением - 6 цифр из текст без букв впереди

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qregexp, std-regex, qregularexpression

Нужно чтобы брало только 6 цифр из текста, но при этом не было никаких доп. букв впереди. Только спец символы, например, такие должны попасть:

```
#009931
№009931
009931
```

А вот такие нет:

```
a009931
b009931
```

Написал что-то похожее, берет только 6-значные числа, но все:

```
(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)
```

Что еще дописать?

Comment: Если спереди нет ни букв, ни цифр (?<![a-zA-Z\d])\d{6}(?!\d).

Answer (score 0):

Проверить можно здесь https://regex101.com/r/6kdJR3/2

```
/(?<!\w)(#|№|)[0-9]{6}/gm
```

Comment: Вместо `\W` лучше `(?<!\w)`, чтобы А - работало в самом начале строки, и Б - этот символ не попадал в результат.

Comment: спасибо, а можно еще дописать, чтобы не брались спец символы, а только цифры?

Comment: @user522193 Исправил, если ответ помог, отметьте его как решение

Comment: Ссылка всё ещё ведёт на старую регулярку. И захватываются не только цифры.

Comment: @topic поменял ссылку

Comment: Ещё ТС в комментарии просил только цифры захватывать.

Comment: @DanilApsadikov да, если можно, что нужно поправить чтобы только цифры захватывал?